# Chrome ignoring audio preload="metadata"

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-audio

My code is basically this

```
<audio controls preload="metadata">
  <source src="linktofile.wav" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

In Firefox 18.0.1 - it results in 8.4 KB data download (checked on Firebug).
But in Chrome 24.0.1312.52 m - it starts downloading the entire file (In developer tools - it shows download size in MBs).

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand preload values are hints for the browser, not absolute commands. In other words, they are a suggestion for how the browser should behave. The browser may or may not follow the hint so don't be surprised if it doesn't always work.

http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/html/audio/preload.html

Answer (score 2):

Version v42 and above now seem to respect this. Yay!
 
(current beta version as of yesterday)

You can see now a `206` partial content request, and 66kb downloaded (my video is 600kb+)

[image]

**However**: VERY IMPORTANT

In case you didn't know, Chrome can only have 6 simultaneous connections at the same time to the same server.

Currently in v42 + v43 they have a terrible bug which means that once the metadata is loaded that file is not released back into the 'pool' for available connections. So if you load 6 or more videos the 7th blocks and won't download.

I've reported this as a bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=468930

This may not be the case for all videos, but I have 10 short MP4 videos encoded with Adobe Media Encoder and they get stuck.

If in doubt, or experiencing this problem you've got no choice but to set `preload='auto'` for now. Hopefully this bug will never make it into the wild.

Comment: I see you're talking audio - this is all for video, not sure if same situation

Comment: looks like a fix may be coming, but the next public release will make the situation worse :-( it seems this has been an issue for much longer than I originally thought

Comment: Supposedly this was fixed however my latest tests show that preload problems are once again back in Chrome. I have had to use preload="none" on my mixed video/audio pages otherwise I end up with super long timeouts on my connections. Firefox and Edge are fine.

Comment: I'm just amazed that such important bugs exist and that there are people smart enough to spot them, flesh them out, and report them!

Comment: @ankush981 I just can’t believe this was five years ago! I always seem to find these kind of bugs - so if that makes me smart I don’t want to be smart anymore

Answer (score 2):

1. preloading is fixed, and has been for a while
2. the behavior with preloading with it holding the connection is **not a bug**.

It keeps the connection open to allow for stream protection by use of one time tokens.

If it didn't do this, the audio or video wouldn't even play if it is protected by a token.

Therefore, chrome MUST keep the connection open until the page is left or closed.